# Line plot with confidence intervals with period datatype on x-axis, seaborn vs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame `df` that looks like this:

```
             DateTime  code  value
0 2021-03-25 16:35:49     1   29.0
1 2021-03-25 16:35:49     2   15.0
2 2021-03-25 16:36:09     1   15.0
3 2021-03-25 16:36:09     2   29.0
4 2021-03-25 16:36:51     1   29.0
...
```

I'd like to make a lineplot of the values with confidence intervals, where the signals are grouped by week. This should be really easy to do with seaborn, but seaborn doesn't seem to allow `Period` datatypes as values for the x-axis. Running this gives an `Invalid object type` error:

```
df['week'] = df.DateTime.dt.to_period('W')
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='week', y='value', hue='code', ci='sd')
```

I can change the datatype to a timestamp and plot:

```
df['week'] = df.DateTime.dt.to_period('W')
df.week = df.week.dt.to_timestamp()
sns.lineplot(data=df, x='week', y='value', hue='code', ci='sd')
```

[image: Line plot with confidence intervals in seaborn, but ugly xaxis labels]

This gives me close to what I want, but I'd rather have the x-axis label look like it would if I had plotted it directly with matplotlib. But I can't figure out an easy way to plot the confidence intervals filled in as they are in the seaborn plot.

```
df['week'] = df.DateTime.dt.to_period('W')
df_week = df.groupby(['week','code'])['value'].agg(['mean']).reset_index()
ax = df_week .query("code==1").plot(x='week', y='mean', label='1')
df_week.query("code==2").plot(ax=ax, x='week', y='mean', label='2')
```

[image: Means plotted directly from dataframe with nice-looking x-axis labels, but no confidence interval]

How can I easily get the plot from the first figure, but with the nice-looking x-axis labels from the second?

Comment: "look like it would if I had plotted it directly with matplotlib"... well you're actually plotting it with pandas (using matplotlib under the hood), which is doing the xlabel formatting.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Is there a way to export the xlabel formatting from one plot to another?

Comment: `fill_between` with alpha option will fill like sns package, but you would need to calculate the std yourself.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate; it's asking about a `Period` dtype which is going to have a different solution from regular `datetime` (which matplotlib can handle natively with its own converters).